# Display particular users data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am doing a project in asp.net mvc. I want to show a particular person's details in the view. I have to join 2 tables to display data. For that I did:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult DisplayData()  
{  
    ViewBag.Designation1up = new SelectList(db.Designations, "Designation1up", "DesignationInternal", "DesignationExternal");  
    return View();  
}  

[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult DisplayData(Employee emp)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        object s = Session["EmployeeID"];  
        var sessval = s.ToString();  
        var data1 = (from e in db.Employees.Where(c => c.EmployeeID == sessval) join d in db.Designations on e.Designation1up equals d.Designation1up select e).SingleOrDefault();  
        return View(data1);  
    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    {  
    }  
    ViewBag.Designation1up = new SelectList(db.Designations, "Designation1up", "DesignationInternal",emp.Designation1up);  
    return View(emp);     
}
```

The view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ResourceTracking.ViewModel.AdminDetailsModel>" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head runat="server"> 
    <title>DisplayData</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <fieldset> 
      <legend>AdminDetailsModel</legend> 
      <div class="display-label">EmployeeID</div> 
      <div class="display-field"> <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmployeeID) %> </div> 
      <!--...(same DIV 4 other fields)-->
   </fieldset>  
  </body> 
</html>
```

My problem is that, when I debug the code, the compiler is not going into the `HttpPost` method. It's just debugging the `HttpGet` method and giving output, but unless `HttpPost` will run, output will not be proper. What should I do for this?

Comment: Could you show the corresponding view?

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ResourceTracking.ViewModel.AdminDetailsModel>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>DisplayData</title>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>AdminDetailsModel</legend>
    
        <div class="display-label">EmployeeID</div>
        <div class="display-field">
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmployeeID) %>
        </div>
    
       ...(same DIV 4 other fields)
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Are you expecting `Html.DisplayFor` to call the `HttpPost` method?

Comment: What part of your code makes you think your post method will ever fire?  Maybe you'd like to take a bit of time and read through [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) to learn some basic concepts of .net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're a little confused about how ASP.NET MVC works. Normally to display data on a view you will call the HttpGet action (DisplayData), create a model, populate it with the relevant data (the employee) and display it.

Something like this (untested)

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult DisplayData()  
{  
    ViewBag.Designation1up = new SelectList(db.Designations, "Designation1up", "DesignationInternal", "DesignationExternal");  

    SomeModel model = new SomeModel();

    object s = Session["EmployeeID"];  
    if (s != null)
    {
        var employeeId = s.ToString();  

        model.EmployeeData = GetEmployeeData(employeeId);
    }

    return View(model);  
}  

private Employee GetEmployeeData(string employeeId)  
{  
    return (from e in db.Employees.Where(c => c.EmployeeID == employeeId) 
            join d in db.Designations 
                on e.Designation1up equals d.Designation1up 
            select e).SingleOrDefault();  
}
```

Comment: Actually, i Am new in asp.net mvc3, so am trying to learn it. and i didnt get any idea about this in any tutorial. Thanks Tyriar for the reply, it was very supportive. thank you, very much